# tkinter, notebook, How to exec one def when select one note?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use tkinter, notebook create one GUI:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title(string = 'The example of ttk notebook')

root.geometry('400x300+200+200')

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = tk.Frame(tabControl, bg = 'blue', width = '400')
tabControl.add(tab1, text = 'information')

tab2 = tk.Frame(tabControl, bg = 'green')
tabControl.add(tab2, text = 'coding')

tab3 = tk.Frame(tabControl, bg = 'yellow')
tabControl.add(tab3, text = 'python')
```

I have one request:
in the gui,

if I select the notebook of information, I want exec one def (such as print(The tab of info has been selected))

if I select the notebook of coding, I want exec one def (such as print(The tab of coding has been selected))

if I select the notebook of python, I want exec one def (such as print(The tab of python has been selected))

How to add the def in the code?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is bind the `ttk.Notebook`. It raises a virtual event

called  `"<<NotebookTabChanged>>"`

```
def print_selected(event):
    text_tab=tabControl.tab(tabControl.select(), "text")
    print(f"Currently selected tab: {text_tab}")

tabControl.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",print_selected)
```